# errors starting a simple spring boot application

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, jpa

Im trying to run a simple spring boot application, i have filled the application.properties with appropriate parameters to creat a datasource based on jpa and mysql configuration, and i have specified in the pom.xml some of the dependencies that my application may require in order to run, but i still get the same error when i start my application, here is my configuration files, i hope i can get some help here !
i want the application to create in my database the table using orm techonolgy for the begining but im stuck with these errors !!

pom.xml file

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>objectExchange</groupId>
<artifactId>exchange</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>objectExchange</name>
<description>ObjectExchange Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

the application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_objexchange
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy  
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

the application file :

```
package com;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ObjectExchangeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ObjectExchangeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

the class for persistance with jpa

```
package com.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
@Entity
public class utilisateur implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    public utilisateur() {
        super();
    }
    public utilisateur(Long id, String nom, String prenom) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }
    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

}
```

this are the file i have on my application and i keep getting these errors :

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.1.RELEASE)

2016-09-25 19:59:02.908  INFO 4952 --- [           main] com.ObjectExchangeApplication            : Starting ObjectExchangeApplication on user-PC with PID 4952 (C:\Users\user\workspace\objectExchange\target\classes started by user in C:\Users\user\workspace\objectExchange)
2016-09-25 19:59:02.918  INFO 4952 --- [           main] com.ObjectExchangeApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-09-25 19:59:03.277  INFO 4952 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1eb5ee5: startup date [Sun Sep 25 19:59:03 WEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-09-25 19:59:05.193  WARN 4952 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/com/mysql/fabric/FabricCommunicationException.class]; nested exception is java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
2016-09-25 19:59:05.284 ERROR 4952 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/com/mysql/fabric/FabricCommunicationException.class]; nested exception is java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:303) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:137) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:275) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:237) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:204) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at com.ObjectExchangeApplication.main(ObjectExchangeApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:463) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:426) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:53) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:279) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted
```

I really hope i can get some help as soon as possible, and thank you all so much !!

Answer (score 4):

#### Your error is this:

> Failed to read candidate component class: URL
> [jar:file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.39/**mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar**!/com/mysql/fabric/FabricCommunicationException.class];
> nested exception is java.util.zip.**ZipException**: invalid LOC header
> (bad signature)

This suggests that `mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar` is corrupt.

#### Solution

Remove `C:/Users/user/.m2/repository` (or at the very least `C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/`).

This will force maven to redownload `mysql-connector-java`'s jar when you rebuild (ie: `mvn clean install`).

Answer (score 0):

Include the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in your POM.xml

Another issue could be the mysql jar located in your .m2 folder. Try to delete the jar file, update your pom.xml and try again.

Comment: i have included both dependencies but, i still get the same error !!

Comment: i have deleted the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependencie, but its is requiered for jpa so it must be included !!

Comment: any other suggestions please ??

Comment: there seems to be something wrong with the mysql jar file as the compiler is not able to unzip it. Did you delete the mysql jar that is located in your .m2 folder?

Comment: yes it worked, i have deleted, the .m2 folder and it worked fine !

Comment: if it was helpful, please don't forget to vote for my solution :D thanks

Answer (score 0):

Working on project I stumble upon the not exact, but rather similar error.

> Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find configuration in: org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.ZipInflaterInputStream@...

In my case the real reason for such error was removing one parameter inside SpringBoot configuration XML file. I don't see real reason for error but fact is....

**Correct** config runs without errors is below:

```
  <beans profile="local,default">
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
```

The **incorrect** configuration causing the same error was removed 'default' param:

```
  <beans profile="local">
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
```

The last configuration was caused the same error on SpringBott app start-up.
The configuration parameters in my case are related to **Apache Ignite**. Cleaning up /.m2/  and Gradle cache folders didn't help.

As one more solution can be running application with specifying explicit Spring profile like:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local xxx_YOUR_FAT_JAR-FILE.jar
```